# Generating a random number to get a random list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, random, listitem

I am trying to get a random list item from a "Quotes" list. I currently have a webpart that has a custom property that is used to select the type of quote to be displayed. The "Quotes" list has quotes for the following categories "corporate, Technology and Finance). Currently I am using a foreach loop that displays all quotes for a specific category. I have CAML query to filter the type of quotes that are to be displayed. The value entered in the custom property of the webpart is used in the CAML query to display the quotes.

The next step is to just display a random quote from a specific category, but I am not too sure on how to achieve this. Below is the code I currenlty have the random bit is not yet completed as not to  sure on how to do it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.PracticeArea != null)
{
string PracticeArea = this.WebPart.PracticeArea; //get the value of the property



//getting a reference to the site location
string webUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs["practices"].Url;

//Getting the Quotes list
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
try
{
//getting the Quotes list
SPList quotesList = web.Lists["Quotes"];

//SPListItemCollection collLisItems = quotesList.Items; not needed

//CAML query to filter or obtain the correct quote based on Area. Value for Area is 
//passed from the custom property and used in the caml query
SPQuery quotesbySector = new SPQuery();

//creating an object to handle our random list item selection
//not too sure whether this is correct
Random rndQuote = new Random();

int num = rndQuote.Next();



//string camlquery1 = "<Where><Eq>" + "<FieldRef Name='Area'/>" + "</Eq></Where>";
string camlquery1 = @"
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Area'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + PracticeArea + @" </Value>
</Eq>
</Where>";

quotesbySector.Query = camlquery1;

SPListItemCollection collListItems = quotesList.GetItems(quotesbySector);

//SPListItem firstQuote = collListItems[0];

//for each loop might need to be removed, as we are only interested in getting a 
//random quote and not all quotes
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
{

string quotes = (string)item["Quote"];
string quotesSource = (string)item["Source"];
string quotesYear = (string)item["Year"];
//string quotesArea = (string)item["Area"]; //not needed used for test purposes

plhQuotes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(quotes + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + quotesSource + 
"<br/>" + "<br/>" + quotesYear + "<br/>" + "<br/>"));

}


}

catch (Exception err)
{
plhErrors.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(err.ToString()));
}
}
}






}

}
```

I am sure there is a simple way to achieve this. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific problem are you facing in your attempt to complete the code?

Comment: Your current code is handling generating a random incorrectly.  Your current code would generate a new random seed, way to often, this would actually result in non-random sequence.  What exactly is not working with what you have, you have not seem to do a critical part in what is required to get help on this website, fully understand what your problem is and only ask a question about that.  You are also going to want to create a number no larger then the size of your collection.  The location of the rndQuote.Next() is correct, the location where you intialize it should be, OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: @Daniel - I am going to downvote this question, until you attempt to full implement what you are trying to do, and you full explain what is and what is not working.  This will allow you to resolve some of the design problem ( i.e. intializing the random class in an incorrect way ) and attempt to get the full scope of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but I have not fully implemented the random mechanism required hence why I have only included the two lines of code dealing with random, the reason being that I am unsure as to how implement it properly (not sure even if it is in the right location in the code) currently random does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry the code you posted seems a bit jumbled around on the formatting but I would do the following:

```
List<String> quoteList = new List<String>();
Random rand = new Random();
String quote;

if(quoteList.Count > 0)
{
  int index = rand.Next(quoteList.Count); // Returns 0 through number of items minus 1
  quote = quoteList[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

- the number of items, `count = collListItems.Count`
- a modulo operation,  `collListItems[randNumber % count]`

Comment: Would it not be easier to use Random.Next(int32,int32) and generate a number between 0 and count?  This would allow him to use the result of that random number as the index value?

Comment: @Ramhound - Slightly easier yes but I thought this to more general and educational.

Answer (score 0):

Have managed to sort this out rather simply. This was done as follows:

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = quotesList.GetItems(quotesbySector);

//Getting a random list item from based on the PracticeArea value entered in webpart's 
//custom property, which is used in the CAML query above to filter the results returned
Random randomQuote = new Random();
int randItem = randomQuote.Next(0, collListItems.Count);

collListItems[randItem].ToString();

SPListItem ourQuote = collListItems[randItem];

string quote = (string)ourQuote["Quote"];
string quoteSource = (string)ourQuote["Source"];
string quoteYear = (string)ourQuote["Year"];

if (quoteYear != null)
{
plhQuotes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(quote + "<br/><br/>" + quoteSource + "<br/>
<br/>" + "Year: " + quoteYear));
}
else
{
plhQuotes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(quote + "<br/><br/>" + quoteSource));
}
```

Sorted!. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you divide the quotes into the proper category list, you can simply get a random and pull an item from the list.

```
//Assuming individual lists for categories (ex: technologyList)
//for technology list
Random random = new Random(seed); //seed is optional
var itemNumber = random.Next(0, technologyList.Count);
return technologyList[itemNumber];
```

This is simple and crude (and assumes you have encapsulated the functionality in a method), but it should give you a basic guidepost. I have not read through the full code sample, so alter this as you need to get your work done.

Comment: It has been my understanding that you should not reintialize an instance of a Random object, each time you want to generate the next random number, since the seed value would keep changing.

Comment: The upper bound of `Random.Next` is non-inclusive, so the second line should read `var itemNumber = random.Next(0, technologyList.Count);`

Comment: @Ramhound the most common pitfall of continually creating new `Random`s is that the seed is based on the system clock, so you get multiple instances with the *same* seed, and the first number returned by each instance is the same.  (Loops generally repeat at a much higher frequency than the frequency at which system clock ticks.)

Comment: Thanks @phoog. Code was written off top of head and I appreciate the guidance to be sure I am not forking things up.

Comment: @Ramhound: Depends on the architecture (setup of the Random). I figured I needed to introduce the concept of a seeded Random in the code, but probably should have caveated the seed in the explanation.

Comment: @phoog - Which is the reason I brought up the fact, he generates a new object and uses the Next(int32,int32) method, which would cause a problem in the situation you describe.  I would even say that Random might even need to be unique per Session in order to work the way the user wants.

Comment: @Gregory -  I really have no problem with your solution, given the context it is used in, it is 100% correct.  If used within a loop it of course wouldn't be valid, the author already does that, which is the reason I wanted to posted the disclaimer.

Comment: @Ramhound that's absolutely correct; I just wanted to point out that the most common problem comes from multiple random instances with the *same* seed, not multiple random instances with *different* seeds.